# Why my FlatList in React-Native doesn't update, even after adding extradata?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, mobile, react-native-flatlist

For the last couple of hours I am trying to make simple list, that you can expand by typing something into text field and pressing button. But it doesn't update my FlatList, even after changing content of extra data. What am I doing wrong?
Please don't mind hard coded ID on updateTask, it is only for debugging.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, StyleSheet, FlatList } from 'react-native'

const DATA = [
  {
    id: '1',
    title: 'First Item',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    title: 'Second Item',
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    title: 'Third Item',
  },
];

function Item({ title }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

class Inputs extends Component {
   state = {
      task: '',
   }
   handleTask = (text) => {
      this.setState({ task: text })
   }
   updateTask = (task) => {
      DATA.push({
        id: '4',
        title: task
      })
      alert(DATA.length + task);
   }
   render() {
      return (
         <View style = {styles.container}>

          <FlatList
             data={DATA}
             renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item.title} />}
             keyExtractor={item => item.id}
             extraData={DATA.length}
          />

            <TextInput style = {styles.input}
               underlineColorAndroid = "transparent"
               placeholder = "Task"
               placeholderTextColor = "#9a73ef"
               autoCapitalize = "none"
               onChangeText = {this.handleTask}/>


            <TouchableOpacity
               style = {styles.submitButton}
               onPress = {
                  () => this.updateTask(this.state.task)
               }>
               <Text style = {styles.submitButtonText}> Submit </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
         </View>
      )
   }
}
export default Inputs

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
      paddingTop: 23
   },
   input: {
      margin: 15,
      height: 40,
      borderColor: '#7a42f4',
      borderWidth: 1
   },
   submitButton: {
      backgroundColor: '#7a42f4',
      padding: 10,
      margin: 15,
      height: 40,
   },
   submitButtonText:{
      color: 'white'
   },
   item: {
    backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 32,
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
extraData={DATA.length}
```

to

```
extraData={this.state}
```

Hope it help.

Comment: It made it better, it now SOMETIMES update, but I can't pinpoint when. It feels like it updates at random

Comment: put your array in state and whenever state will be changed .It will re-render.(sorry for bad EN)